# Read all xml files in a folder and save them in a datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I have a folder with a bunch of files which i would like to read and parse and save some values into a table which i will be inserting in a SQL database. The folder looks something like this. C:\document\vehicles. And inside the folders i have files like:
BMW.xml, Audi.xml, Volvo.xml
And inside each files a have a bunch of nodes but the node that im interested in looks like:

```
<FpcBlock Version="01">
        <FPC Name="1" Value="A" Updated="false" />
        <FPC Name="3" Value="B" Updated="false" />
<FpcBlock Version="01">
```

I would like to save the FPC Name and the Value into a table which should look like:

[image: Datatable example]

This should go on until all the values are read and then i would like to continue to the next file which is Audi and continue to fill in the table. 
Currently i have not managed to read the first file at all. Any ideas how i should move on?

My current code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    DirectoryInfo difo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\ahodhv\Perforce\ahodhv_RD0029717_1921\prod\delivery\q_rec\int_test\SOPS");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo[] Files = difo.GetFiles("*.xml");            
        string[] parts;

        foreach (FileInfo File in Files)
        {
            parts = File.Name.Split('_');                                             
            boxvehicles.Items.Add(parts[0]);
            doc.Load(File.DirectoryName);
            XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("FpcBlock Version");
            string text = node.InnerText;             
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: I have not written any code at all yet. I don't know how to start.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a great site to do all your work. You're supposed to do some of the effort, for example by reading [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzb96fk.aspx). That should always get you started. Please use [the checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to improve the post and at least replace the picture with an xml users can copy paste ...

Comment: Im not asking you to do all the work. I need suggestions on how i should move forward. I have tried MSDN and i don't understand. That is why i asked here.

Comment: It seems like you want people on Stackoverflow to solve you college homework. Please put some effort and use google for every step, you can google how to parse/deserialize xml files/data, then google how to put data into a database.

Comment: Besides you didn't even mention your database technology, is it MSSQL, NPGSQL, What type of framework are you using, EntityFramework and so on. Then you can start with show the code you have wrote so far so people can help you.

Comment: check out the new Documentation area. For example http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1528/xmldocument-and-the-system-xml-namespace/7647/reading-from-xml-document & http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/4266/file-and-stream-i-o/16606/files-and-directories

Comment: @SofteEng i have posted my code now. And no, this is not for a collage work. I'm trying to learn but i just don't know how to do it. I'm not trying to make you guys do all the work but i need help since i'm stuck and quite new to programming

Comment: what is boxvehicles for a kind of control?

Comment: Sorry, bowvehicles is just a listbox. Where all the vehicle name are just added. I use split since the name are like bumblebee_2111. Where the number are kilometers it have been droven.

Comment: [Start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0z9zxd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hello @AdnanHossain , are these Scania Sops File parameteres? can you help me with the *.sops files about scania trucks programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first your xml is wrong, it should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FpcBlock Version="01">
        <FPC Name="1" Value="A" Updated="false" />
        <FPC Name="3" Value="B" Updated="false" />
        <FPC Name="5" Value="B" Updated="false" />
        <FPC Name="8" Value="B" Updated="false" />
        <FPC Name="10" Value="B" Updated="false" />
        <FPC Name="11" Value="A" Updated="false" />
        <FPC Name="14" Value="Q" Updated="false" />
</FpcBlock>
```

Then you need to create C# objects to deserialize your xml to.

```
[Serializable()]

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "FPC")]
    public class FPC
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Updated")]
        public string Updated { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "FpcBlock")]
    public class FpcBlock
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FPC")]
        public List<FPC> FPC { get; set; }
    }
```

Then make the call like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            FpcBlock cars = null;
            var path = @"C:\temp\car.xml";

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FpcBlock));

            var reader = new StreamReader(path);
            cars = (FpcBlock)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
        }
```

I have tested this code and it works like a charm. Now you do not need to put them in a datatable then into database, then you can insert the objects directly into the database using EntityFrameWork.

(One more thing, **NEVER IMPLEMENT YOUR LOGIC INSIDE A BUTTON EVENT**), this is call bad practice.

Please mark it as an Answer if it works you